# ;jsessionid in url with angualrjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsessionid

The angular js app has to be loaded on a redirect response from some java-based auth engine. The url looks like:

```
Location:https://localhost:8081/#/login;jsessionid=nw41zgc9w0481xafcsotnu7kw?&lang=en&country=EN&
```

the ";jsessionid" seems to cause all the paramaters to disappear from " $location.search()" retruned object. For the second request to the server, that is when browser sends cookie installed with the fist request, jsessionid is absent in rediect url and everything works fine.

Thus the question is - how to handle jsessionid in url with angular?

Comment: 1. you should configure your server to send: #login?jsesionid=nw...&lang=...&..=..
2. You'll need to store jsessionid cookie with JS on your browser.

Comment: no way, the server is out of my reach